# How can I insert a .csv file into a specific worksheet on a daily basis?

Tags: csv, google-apps-script, google-docs

I have a folder in my google drive that automatically receives a new .csv file everyday. My goal would be to select the most recently uploaded .csv file in the folder and insert it into a specific worksheet (overwriting what was there previously) in a google sheet . This would have to be done on a daily basis (let's say at 18:00h GMT).﻿

Comment: Have you tried writing any script for this problem? If so, can you share it.? What does the sheet look like?

Comment: You'd probably need to access the folder and check the [getDateCreated()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getDateCreated()) to check which file you need to select. Then use [SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app) to read the file and write it in your file (or use the build-in ImportRange function) and use a [time trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) to fire the script

Comment: I have not yet tried to write a script. The sheet is simply 3 different worksheets and I would like for the csv's data to overwrite the data on a worksheet called 'Raw Data' on a daily basis.

Comment: that is a specification, not a coding question. show us coding attempts. the drive api lets you automatically create a spreadsheet from a csv. you could also read the csv and write to the spreadsheet directly.

Answer (score 0):

You create a time based trigger From Edit/Current Project triggers.  Point it to loadingCSV.

```
  function loadingCSV() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById("spreadsheetID");
  var sht=ss..getSheetByName("sheet name");
  sht.clearContents();
  var data = loadFile('my.csv','folderID')
  var dataA =Utilities.parseCsv(data);
  var rng = sht.getRange(1, 1, dataA.length, dataA[0].length)
  rng.setValues(dataA);
}

function loadFile(filename,folderID)
{
  var fldr = DriveApp.getFolderById('folderID');
  var file = fldr.getFilesByName(filename);
  var s = '';
  while(file.hasNext())
  {
    var fi = file.next();
    var target = fi.getName();
    if(target == filename)
    {
      s = fi.getBlob().getDataAsString();
    }
  }
  return s;
}
```